# Sometimes view not updated completely

Tags: angularjs

Parts of a view of my Angular app are not rendered correctly - **sometimes**.
The behaviour is very strange, because this happens only sometimes and for certain items only.

My app consists of a service, a controller and a view. The service communicates with a backend and provides data for the controller. The controller is watching for certain data. With data-binding the values are shown in the view.

In general the shown values are correctly - I can see it in the logs. But sometimes when the a value has changed, not all depended view elements get updated - but some of them.
I mean a `DIV` shows the text of a certain value with `ng-bind`.
Moreover another `DIV` is visible or hidden with `ng-if` and depends on the same value of the same controller.

Sometimes I have the behaviour that the visibility of the button is switch correctly but the text of the other `DIV` does not (shows the old text).
It switches **only if I scroll the view** (or touch it on mobile device). Is this the next digest cycle maybe?

Otherwhile everything is rendered complete correctly!

I have already tried it with a directive and without one, with the 'controllerAs' syntax and without, with Angular 1.2 and 1.3 - but everytime the same result.

Has anyone further ideas to this behaviour?
Can this be a rendering problem?